# Rails subdomains for different evironments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, subdomain

I have a rails app, that I am currently shifting to production. But I want to setup a subdomain such that, 
if I goto : 
dev.myapp.com , I reach the development environment & if I goto
prod.myapp.com , I reach the production environment

Will I have to use 2 instances for this purpose, or can this managed by one?

My servers are on AWS, and domain is managed by GoDaddy

Comment: 2 instances of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use both environments on the same server but you would have to have 2 different instances running.

You can use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [Apache HTTPD](https://httpd.apache.org/) to route the different domains (or sub-domains) to the actual instance running on your server (if it's an AWS EC2).

You have several other ways to configure it depending on your setup.

Comment: But will, I need two EC2 instances or one ? Cause when I try running a second (prod) instance of a rails server on a different port, it gives me an error saying there is a server that is already running. So is it possible to run 2 servers on the same EC2 instance ?

Comment: You can have just one EC2 instance. The easiest way would be to use nginx or apache httpd with [phusion passanger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need separate instances of the application running; the choice of running environment is a global, boot-time decision, with wide-ranging effects.

It's totally possible to run both of those application instances on the same server (AWS EC2 instance)... though it's more traditional to run the development mode on a local development machine, safely distanced from production.